# How to fetch very particular elements from a list?

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, list, numpy

I have a list of dataframes with different shapes, which is why I cant put the data into a 3-dimensional df or array.
Now I want to get some specific dataframes from that list in a new list now containing only the needed dfs.

```py
list_of_df = [df1, df2, df3, ...]
index = [0,3,7,9,29,11,18,77,1009]
new_list = list_of_df[index]
```

the only way I can think of this is very unsexy:

```py
new_list = []
for i in index:
   new_list.append(list_of_df[i])
```

is there some better solution or in general a more convenient way to store and access thousands of different dataframes?

Comment: `new_list = np.array(list_of_df)[index]`?

Comment: yeah you're right thanks, I was always going for np.asarray(list_of_df)[index] which didn't work then not sure what changed but yeah that's somehow working now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the Answer of @Quang Hoang solves the issue:

`new_list = np.array(list_of_df)[index]`

Answer (score 1):

You can use a list comprehension:

```
new_list = [df for (i, df) in enumerate(list_of_df) if i in index]
```